# expected expression, got '}'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass the following content into a jquery variable but when I click on it it says expected expression, got }. It has to do with the quotation right? How am I supposed to use double and single quotes in this instance?

```
var content = $("<div class='channel' id='general' onclick='jumpToFirstLevelRoom('general')'>General</div>")
```

Comment: The problem is somewhere inside your `jumpToFirstLevelRoom`, and not here. Add the code to that function as well, so that we may see. Secondly, try debugger in your browser to see why is `}` being passed there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes your quotes are wrong. You have unescaped single quotes inside single quotes.

You should use either of these quotation techniques :

- Different quotes :

  ```
  var content = $("<div class='channel' id='general' onclick='jumpToFirstLevelRoom(`general`)'>General</div>")
  ```
- Escaped quotes :

  ```
  var content = $("<div class='channel' id='general' onclick='jumpToFirstLevelRoom(\'general\')'>General</div>")
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Thank god for double, single, and backticks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the escape sequence to remove the double quot from the variable.

```
var content = $("<div class=\"channel\" id=\"general\" onclick=\"jumpToFirstLevelRoom('general')\">General</div>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your current code

```
var content = $("<div class='channel' id='general' onclick='jumpToFirstLevelRoom('general')'>General</div>")
```

**to**

```
var content = $("<div class='channel' id='general' onclick='jumpToFirstLevelRoom(\'general\')'>General</div>");
```

Just use `escape` `characters`.

With es6 you can do

```
var content = $(`<div class='channel' id='general' onclick='jumpToFirstLevelRoom("general")'>General</div>`);
```

Hope this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is this:

```
var content = $("<div class='channel' id='general' enter code hereonclick='jumpToFirstLevelRoom(\'general\')'>General</div>");
```

You need to use escape characters to remove double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I got the problem in your code. The problem is in that statement where you are calling a function and passing arguments.

```
var content = $("<div class='channel' id='general' onclick='jumpToFirstLevelRoom('general')'>General</div>")
```

You are passing a string **general** in function **jumpToFirstLevelRoom('general')**. 
So when you are starting single quotes of string **general**, It is behaving as closing quote of **onclick='** .

Try to not pass the string in the function as argument. Then the code will run.
I hope it will help you. :)